# How can a Windows Forms ListView be programmatically scrolled left/right?

Tags: winforms, listview

How can a Windows Forms ListView be programmatically scrolled left/right?

Maybe a SendMessage can be sent to the control's horizontal scrollbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
[DllImport("user32")]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr Handle, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam,
IntPtr lParam);

protected void ScrollH(int pixelsToScroll)
{
const Int32 LVM_FIRST = 0x1000;
const Int32 LVM_SCROLL = LVM_FIRST + 20;
SendMessage(lvwList.Handle, LVM_SCROLL, (IntPtr) pixelsToScroll,
IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks James!